# Accessing LocalStorage in Headless Chrome Using Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm running Selenium from Python on the Mac and running into an error with headless Chrome. 
Here is my headless chrome setup. I'm loading a default chrome profile that has one extension: ModHeader

My setup is as follows

```
 chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
 chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
 chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent={}".format(USER_AGENT))
 chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
 chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/test/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I want to use [ProxyMesh](http://www.proxymesh.com) with a specific IP address for requests. So I access localstorage to set the proper header in ModHeader

```
 driver.execute_script(
  "localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{                " +
     "  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '',           " +
     "  headers: [                                                      " +
     "   {enabled: true, name: 'X-ProxyMesh-IP', value: '%s', comment: ''}"%ip_address +
     "  ],                                                              " +
     "  respHeaders: [],                                                " +
     "  filters: []                                                     " +
     "}]));                                                        ")
```

The problem, which doesn't occur when I don't run headless Chrome, is that when I try to run the driver.execute_script I run into the following error.

> Message: move target out of bounds: Failed to read the 'localStorage'
>   property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

Are you not able to access localstorage using headless chrome? Is there something I need to change with my configuration? Any ideas would be appreciated?

Comment: Try taking a screenshot. Where you are trying to 'move', might not be displayed. A screenshot will help you diagnose what is happening.

Comment: I just go to example.com and then executescript

Comment: I'm not moving anywhere. Just                 driver.get("http://www.example.com")
time.sleep(.5) then the driver.executescript above

Comment: I've figured it out. I was shuffling through several proxies and one of my proxies was an open proxy and was causing the issues. It was not properly loading example.com and then thus the script wasn't able to execute.

Comment: Awesome. What does the fixed code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I got an error message "Error Loading Extension" using python selenium with Chrome Browser.
Code below which will work for this.

```
executable_path = 'Path/chromedriver.exe'   ---Where your Chrome driver.exe
capabilities = { 'chromeOptions':  { 'useAutomationExtension': False}}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path,desired_capabilities = capabilities)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```